# Give an example of $\liminf_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \lt \liminf_{k \to \infty} (a_k)^{\frac{1}{k}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Question :

Give an example of a sequence $a_k$ with positive numbers such that :
$\liminf_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \lt \liminf_{k \to \infty} (a_k)^{\frac{1}{k}} \lt \limsup_{k \to \infty} (a_k)^{\frac{1}{k}} \lt \limsup_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$

Note 1: The middle inequality is easy but with those two ( right and left ) it seems hard to find an example. Any hint would be great !

**Note 2: All the four values of inequality should be finite.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just make every other term really small.

Comment: @Gaffney How exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all four numbers to be finite, the following idea can be used instead. Define
$$
b_k=\begin{cases}
2,&\text{if $2^{n-1}<k\le2^n$ for odd $n$},\\
1,&\text{if $2^{n-1}<k\le2^n$ for even $n$},\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $k=1$, $2$, ... (so, the sequence of $b_k$ is $1$, $2$, $1$, $1$, $2$, $2$, $2$, $2$ etc.). After that define
$$
a_k=\prod_{n=1}^kb_n.
$$
This way, $\liminf_{k\to\infty}a_{k+1}/a_k=\liminf_{k\to\infty}b_k=1$, $\limsup_{k\to\infty}a_{k+1}/a_k=\limsup_{k\to\infty}b_k=2$.

As for the upper and lower limits of the $n$-th root of $a_n$:
$$
\liminf_{k\to\infty}a_k^{1/k}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2^{2n}}^{1/2^{2n}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}({2^{1+4+\dots+2^{2n-2}}})^{1/2^{2^n}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}(2^{(2^{2n}-1)/3})^{1/2^{2^n}}=2^{1/3},
$$
$$
\limsup_{k\to\infty}a_k^{1/k}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2^{2n+1}}^{1/2^{2n+1}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}({2^{1+4+\dots+2^{2n}}})^{1/2^{2^n+1}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}(2^{(2^{2n+2}-1)/3})^{1/2^{2^n+1}}=2^{2/3}.
$$
So, the example is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 6):

If you define
$$
a_k=\begin{cases}
2^k&\text{if $k$ is odd},\\
4^k&\text{if $k$ is even},
\end{cases}
$$
then
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2^{k+1}}{4^k}=0,\\
\liminf_{k\to\infty}a_k^{1/k}&=2,\\
\limsup_{k\to\infty}a_k^{1/k}&=4,\\
\limsup_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{4^{k+1}}{2^k}=+\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: Excuse me ... but the question wants all the 4 values to be finite ... can u modify your answer? i know the mistake was from me and i'm so sorry :)